# Number of Sylow $p$-subgroups is congruent to $1$ modulo $p^a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group having more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup. Let $p^a$ be the least element of $\{|P|/|P\cap Q|: P,Q\in \operatorname{Syl}_p(G),P\neq Q\}$. Prove $n_p\equiv 1\pmod {p^a}$.

I do not know how to prove it. Could anyone give a help? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup $G.$ Let $P$ act by conjugation on all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ and consider the length of the orbits other than $\{P \}$.

Comment: @JonathanY. I don't see how those two things can be unclear. There are only two natural choices for orderings, and they are equal in this case. And what else would the mod mean other than the usual?

Comment: Yes, yes, I'm sorry. I read that wrong.

Comment: I am still confused

Comment: Dear Prof. I am still confused could you explain more? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before proving I will state a lemma;

**Lemma:** if $P$ is element of $Syl_p(G)$ and $H$ is p group then $H\cap{N_G(P)}=H\cap{P}$. it is a standart lemma used for proving sylow theorems.

Now let $P$ be element of $Syl_p(G)$ and $P$ act on  $Syl_p(G)$ by conjugation. Then evrey orbit has a length $|P:P\cap{N_G(Q)}|$ by orbit stabilizer theorem. By our lemma, it is equal$|P:P\cap{Q}|$.Notice that length of orbit is 1 if and only if $P=Q$. Now for rest of orbits find Q such that  $|P:P\cap{Q}|$ is as small as pasible then it divides rest of orbits lengths which are not one and we know that there is only one orbit with length one then result follows.

Thus, $n_p≡1 \ mod \ |P:P\cap{Q}|$

---

**proof of the lemma:**

Notice that $P$ is also  element of $Syl_p(N_G(P))$ and since  $H\cap{N_G(P)}$ is a p group in $N_G(P)$ then it must be contained in $P$ thus  $H\cap{N_G(P)}<H\cap{P}$ the other inclusion is obvious thus we are done.