# A Lemma about Sylow Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Can you help me prove a lemma, please? It would be very useful for several problems in Sylow theory. I tried a couple of ways to prove it but unsuccessfully.

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=p^nq$, where $p$ is prime, and $(p,q)=1$. Let $n_p$ be the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups.
Prove that either $n_p\equiv 1\pmod {p^2}$ or there exist two Sylow $p$-subgroups $P_1$ and $P_2$ such that $|P_1\cap P_2|=p$.

Comment: Do you know about group actions? If yes, then try the action of $G$ on the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups by conjugation, and look at this action restricted to a (fixed) Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$. How many fixed points (= orbits of length $1$) does the action restricted to $S$ have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1**: Let a given Sylow subgroup act by conjugation on the set of all Sylow subgroups.  What are the sizes of the orbits?

**Hint 2**: [Here's a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483732/number-of-sylow-p-subgroups-is-congruent-to-1-modulo-pa).  It's not quite exactly the same question, but it's close.  See how you can use it with your situation.

**Answer**:

> Using the second hint, if $p^a = \text{min}([P:P\cap Q] \ | \ P\neq Q\in\text{Syl}_p(G))$, then $n_p\equiv 1\bmod p^a$.  Now $a=1$ if and only if $[P: P\cap Q]=p$ for some $Q\in\text{Syl}_p(G)$, and if $a>1$ then $p^2$ divides $p^a$ and so $n_p\equiv 1\bmod p^2$.  This gives your desired result.